# neo4j version 4.0.0 docker container resets password on restart

Tags: docker, neo4j

I am running a version 4.0.0 neo4j docker image. The initial username/password combination is neo4j/test. I update the password while connected to the system database, as well as via the webapp using the following command `:server change-password`. Everytime i stop the container (I use it for local development, so when i shutdown my laptop, the container is shutdown as well), the password is reset. How do I make the password survive restarts of the container?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use volume (`--volume n4j:/data`). Volumes are the way of persistence.

I tried to run the following :

```
docker run \
  -p 7474:7474 \
  -p 7687:7687 \
  --volume n4j:/data \
  --name neo -d neo4j:4.0.0
```

- i navigate to http://localhost:7474
- i login with neo4j/neo4j
- i changed the password from neo4j to **neo4j123**
- I stop the container : `docker stop neo`
- i deleted the container : `docker rm neo`

but see... the volume 'n4j' is still there `docker volume ls` .

- now, i will run new container with the same volume.
- navigate to http://localhost:7474
- authenticate with the **neo4j123** , it works!!

Comment: demo will expire after 2 hours http://ip172-18-0-20-bpdcvknnctv0008vjcgg-7474.direct.labs.play-with-docker.com/browser/